# Why don't badges come with reputation points?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

I thought that badges could bring with them some reputation points. Example:

- Bronze - 5 points
- Silver - 10 points
- Gold - 20 points

Is this a bad idea? Just curiosity.

Please don't misunderstood me, this is **not a suggestion**, just a discussion to figure out why this systems is not this way.

Comment: What justification would there be for this? Given that a lot of badges come from earning reputation this is unnecessary.

Comment: @Scroodge I don't know, just thought that. But many badges doesn't come for just earning reputation.

Comment: Great suggession.....

Comment: @sarinjacob It's just a discussion, I'm don't suggesting it.

Comment: I have removed my downvote since you're just asking why it's a bad idea, not suggesting it.

Comment: @TheUnhandledException if you see my first post(ok, I write very bad in english) but my real point was always the question and not the suggestion. But somebody edited it and change the point.

Comment: I see now @Márcio. Your last paragraph makes it very clear now! Sorry for the doanvote... and in case you don't know, [downvotes mean disagreement on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: I would add to that a new badge proposal: “recursive: earned reputation due to a badge awarded”.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this is somewhat counter to the idea of badges and reputation.

**Reputation** is (to a certain extent) a measure of how much the community trusts you, and how much you've contributed to the community.

**Badges** are more like Achievements (on XBOX or World of Warcraft, for instance) - they are, more or less, bragging rights.  Something to show off.  They also help to encourage certain positive behaviors (see the Reviewer badge, for instance).

I don't think it's a terrible idea (especially with such small quantities you listed above), but I don't think it really makes sense in the current system.

Comment: Yeah, badges and rep are two different kinds of rewards, they should not be linked.

Comment: Great point of view you have. I see two possibilities, one is that I've posted here, the other is the same you've posted.

Answer (score 5):

Badges are designed to be different than reputation in a few ways, one of which is that they're meant to be pleasant surprises to many people.  Much like achievements, as mentioned by jadarnel27 in [another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116246/167443). Yes, you can look up how to get them, but unlike rep, where we really want all new users to understand how to earn it, badges are designed to usually elicit more of a:

> Oh, I got a badge for doing that?  Cool!

But here's the direct answer to your question:

**Many badges are awarded for behaviors that are desirable, but shouldn't, in and of themselves, get you the privileges that high-rep users get, because they don't indicate the same *trustworthitude* as getting upvotes on content.**

You wouldn't want to grant editing or closure power to someone who's not getting upvotes on questions or answers, but has tons of badges in things like upvoted comments (which are sometimes more funny than helpful), retags (which aren't always helpful), consecutive visits (which don't reflect expertise), etc.

Plus, if badges unlocked privileges, you'd likely see more grinding for them in undesirable ways, like people linking to their posts indiscriminately to get the page view-based ones, etc.

Comment: You make some good points. Maybe the solution is ***badge points***. They we can have the best of both (point badge) worlds.

Answer (score 0):

I think badges ***should*** come with points. When you earn a badge but get no points, it feels empty.

Two good reasons:

**Motivation** - Whenever people get points (most) feel motivated to do more.

**Reputation** - Measure of trust and contribution.

If reputation is a measure of how much you have you have contributed to the community, then badges should have points attached to them. When you earn a badge, you have made a significant contribution.

However, the point values do not need to be life changing:

```
Bronze - 10 points
Silver - 25 points
Gold - 100 points
```